# Java JNDI lookup to Microsoft Active Directory (using Tomcat 6), authentication failing

Tags: java, jsp, active-directory, tomcat6, jndi

The idea is to perform an authentication (basic form with username + password) by configuring my Tomcat 6 container so that it connects (using JNDI Realm) to Microsoft Active Directory to check whether or not credentials are correct.

I have found quite a few documentation on the subject but I fail to configure the Realm properly I believe.

This is the documentation I found on Oracle's website (which happens to be the same since Tomcat 4) http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm

Found this Oracle doc pretty poor but came across other websites such as this one http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/ActiveDirectoryIntegration which elaborate on the subject.

However after many attempts I still cannot authenticate successfully:

1. When I start Tomcat, everything seems fine, no WARNING or any other error message appears.
2. When I try to authenticate, I am consistently redirected to my error page. And no WARNING or any other message appears.

These are 2 of the Realm configs I tried

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
   connectionName="test"
   connectionPassword="test"
   connectionURL="LDAP://subDomain.myDomain.co.uk:389"
   userPattern="uid={0},ou=London,dc=subDomain,dc=myDomain,dc=co,dc=uk"
   roleBase="ou=London,dc=subDomain,dc=myDomain,dc=co,dc=uk"
   roleName="cn"
   roleSearch="memberUid={1}"
/>

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
  connectionName="test"
  connectionPassword="test"
  connectionURL="LDAP://subDomain.myDomain.co.uk:389"
  userBase="ou=London,dc=subDomain,dc=myDomain,dc=co,dc=uk"
  userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
  roleBase="ou=Groups,dc=subDomain,dc=myDomain,dc=co,dc=uk"
  roleName="cn"
  roleSubtree="true"
  roleSearch="(member={0})"
/>
```

I have tested the connection credential using an LDAP browser and they are fine.

This is my web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Example Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>London</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <!-- Default a login configuration that uses form-based authentication -->
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>DBRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>

  <!-- Define a logical role for this application, needs to be mapped to an actual role at deployment time -->
  <security-role>
    <description>All Users</description>
    <role-name>London</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance,
A.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the uid or memberUid attributes in AD? Those are atypical.

You probably want to replace the `uid=` in your `userPattern` with `cn=`.

For roleSearch, that's probably actually supposed to be `member=`.

Comment: I changed uid= in my userPattern with cn= but no luck.
Is the roleSearch field mandatory?

Comment: I added the 2nd Realm config tested that also failed in my question above. Still not working. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know anything about JNDI - just coming at this from an AD perspective. By far, the best way to troubleshoot this is to get a network capture and open it in WireShark. You'll be able to see exactly what's being sent to AD and tweak accordingly. I can assist based on that.